# "sbt package" command hanging always while preparing spark target jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

While trying to prepare spark jar by using the "sbt package" command it always hanging , i understand that it may need to download some jars from repository but waited till more than 30 min , no progress , tried couple of times. my n/w speed on centOS is good.
I was doing sample spark programming :- 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/quick-start.html

My folder structure looks like this :-

```
$ find .
.
./simple.sbt
./src
./src/main
./src/main/scala
./src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala
```

and I am running

```
# Package a jar containing your application
$ sbt package
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.12 ...
```

Takes too long time , please let me know any reason or fix i can . Thanks

Adding the stack trace if can point out the reason :-

```
[cloudera@quickstart scalaprg]$ jps
2201 sbt-launch.jar
2464 Jps
17046 SparkSubmit

[cloudera@quickstart scalaprg]$ jstack 2201
2016-08-30 02:12:33
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0c4001000 nid=0x932 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f03a0800 nid=0x906 waiting on condition [0x00007fb0e497f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache.run(KeepAliveCache.java:172)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f0117800 nid=0x8a3 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f0115800 nid=0x8a2 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f0112800 nid=0x8a1 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f0108000 nid=0x8a0 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f00f1000 nid=0x89f in Object.wait() [0x00007fb0e57fa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000eaa85568> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000000eaa85568> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f00ed000 nid=0x89e in Object.wait() [0x00007fb0f415c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000eaa850f0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000000eaa850f0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f0008800 nid=0x89a runnable [0x00007fb0f62a3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    - locked <0x00000000edcf93c8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    - locked <0x00000000edcffb98> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    - locked <0x00000000f5b04440> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
    - locked <0x00000000f5abe568> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.checkStatusCode(BasicURLHandler.java:130)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.getURLInfo$57a0216e(BasicURLHandler.java:73)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.getURLInfo(BasicURLHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLResource.init(URLResource.java:65)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLResource.exists(URLResource.java:81)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.check(BasicResolver.java:1007)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.getAndCheck(BasicResolver.java:982)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver$6.download(BasicResolver.java:1144)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager$BackupResourceDownloader.download(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:1396)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.download(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:884)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.cacheModuleDescriptor(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:1169)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.parse(BasicResolver.java:536)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.getDependency(BasicResolver.java:271)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver.getDependency(ChainResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:169)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:714)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:594)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:234)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:105)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:99)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    - locked <0x00000000eb1f4210> (a xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:350)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$retrieve$1(Launch.scala:208)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:216)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:216)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:196)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    - locked <0x00000000eaf39908> (a xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f00ea800 nid=0x89d runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f001e000 nid=0x89b runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f0020000 nid=0x89c runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fb0f0122800 nid=0x8a4 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 231
```

Comment: Try to set the log level on Debug before you compile and see what happens: in the sbt shell "logLevel in compile := Level.Debug". And first of all try to compile, so in the sbt shell ";clean;compile"

Comment: thanks , i will try ,

Comment: Compile is fast , no problem in that . only sbt package is too slow. I checked the n/w using nload command the speed is okay its 5 MBps